# DRY way to declare several similar form fields

Tags: python, django

Let's say I'm trying to declare a (django) Form class with several FileFields:

```
class = MyForm(forms.Form):
    file_0 = forms.FileField()
    file_1 = forms.FileField()
    ...
```

I have about 20 sequential inputs to declare - what's the best way to avoid typing this all out like a chump?

Comment: take a look at formsets.

Comment: I'm aware that it could be done that way, but I'm trying to find out if there's a "lighter weight" way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Django dynamic Form generation

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for i in range(20):
            self.fields["file_%d" % i] = forms.FileInput()
```

See Docs [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookNewFormsDynamicFields).

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop:

```
files = [forms.FileInput() for i in range(20)]
```

Comment: Goes without saying, of course, that these files have to be accessed by index, e.g. `files[0]`

Comment: It's not clear to me how the Meta class would access these, nor how class methods would access the Fields if they're just in a list like that.